# Metamask – Trying to call a function on a non-contract address

Tags: metamask

I am receiving the following alert from Metamask.

`ALERT: Trying to call a function on a non-contract address.`

The address is most certainly a contract address, I can interact with it perfectly through the geth console.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are connected to the proper network through Metamask, the network that the contract is deployed on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the browser and login Metamask again. I resolved the issue after did it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to update my ABI JSON file. After the update, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue that you changed your contract but haven't redeployed it.

Compile first:

```
truffle compile
```

and then redeploy:

```
truffle migrate --reset
```

Check your app again.

Answer (score 0):

My ganache instance restarted since the original deployment and I had to redeploy the contract, in order to get it to work.

`truffle migrate --reset`

Please like this post, so I'm able to support other contributors who helped me out.

Answer (score -1):

It was a problem for me too. Initially I was working on rinkeby, then I switched network to main and then again to rinkeby.
It worked fine for me after that.